# Clone linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)


struct list_node
{
    char* name;
    struct list_node* contact;
    struct list_node* next;
};



struct list_node* create_list()
{
    struct list_node* nodes[10];
    int i;

    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        nodes[i] = (struct list_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
    }

    
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        nodes[i]->next = nodes[i + 1];
    }
    nodes[9]->next = NULL;

    nodes[0]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("John") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[0]->name, "John");
    nodes[0]->contact = nodes[1];

    nodes[1]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("Mary") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[1]->name, "Mary");
    nodes[1]->contact = nodes[9];

    nodes[2]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("Mohamed") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[2]->name, "Mohamed");
    nodes[2]->contact = nodes[0];

    nodes[3]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("Liza") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[3]->name, "Liza");
    nodes[3]->contact = nodes[4];

    nodes[4]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("Osenya") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[4]->name, "Osenya");
    nodes[4]->contact = nodes[4];

    nodes[5]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("Peter") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[5]->name, "Peter");
    nodes[5]->contact = nodes[7];

    nodes[6]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("Mahala") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[6]->name, "Mahala");
    nodes[6]->contact = nodes[2];

    nodes[7]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("Rita") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[7]->name, "Rita");
    nodes[7]->contact = nodes[4];

    nodes[8]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("Jacques") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[8]->name, "Jacques");
    nodes[8]->contact = nodes[8];

    nodes[9]->name = (char*)malloc(strlen("Paul") + 1);
    strcpy(nodes[9]->name, "Paul");
    nodes[9]->contact = nodes[1];


    return nodes[0];
}


void print_list(struct list_node* l)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (l != NULL)
    {
        printf("Entry %d is %s, contact is %s\n", i, l->name, l->contact->name);
        i++;
        l = l->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


struct list_node* copy_list(struct list_node* original)
{
    if (original == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        struct list_node* tmp = (struct list_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));


        char a = (char)&(original->name);
        tmp->name = original->name;
        tmp->contact = original->contact;

        tmp->next = copy_list(original->next);

        return tmp;
    }
}


struct list_node* delete_list(struct list_node* l)
{
    struct list_node* tmp;
    while (l != NULL)
    {
        tmp = l->next;

        free(l->name);
        l->name = NULL;
        l->contact = NULL;
        l->next = NULL;

        free(l);

        l = tmp;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    struct list_node* original = NULL;
    struct list_node* copy = NULL;

    //create linked list
    original = create_list();

    //print linked list
    printf("Original:\n");
    print_list(original);

    //copy linked list
    copy = copy_list(original);

    //delete original linked list
    original = delete_list(original);

    //print copy
    printf("Copy:\n");
    //should print exactly the same thing as the original
    print_list(copy);
}
```

I was working on some code and I don't know how to approach the problem. I was given all that code other than the copy_list() function which I had to write myself. When running the code my compiler gives me the error *Exception thrown at 0x7BF71F4C (ucrtbased.dll) in lab2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDDD.* I assume this is because in the main a copy of the linked list is made and the original is deleted; that mixed with the way my copy_list() is set up is causing some sort of problem. How would I go about fixing this and modifying the copy_list() function?

Comment: "*I don't know how to approach the problem*". First thing to do it to learn to debug effectively so that you can find the problem yourself. Run your program in a debugger and/or add debug print statements to trace the program execution to find where the crash happens and where things start going wrong. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `tmp->name = original->name;` That just points the new node's name to the same memory as the original name. And that memory becomes invalid when the original list is deleted. Instead, make a copy: `tmp->name = strdup(original->name)`. Similar problem for the `contact` field.

Comment: You're doing a shallow copy.  That is, you are preserving the original pointers.  So both the `name` and the `contact` fields become invalid after you delete the original list.  As part of the copy, you need to copy the strings to newly allocated storage (easy), and you need to make the `contact` fields point to the *copied* nodes (more difficult, since it requires a mapping from old to new nodes).